# Proposition about localizations of Dedekind domains - Lang: Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

This proposition is in Lang's book "Algebraic number theory":

"Let $A$ be a Dedekind ring and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $A$. Then $S^{-1}A$ is a Dedekind ring. The map $\mathfrak{a}\mapsto S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}$ is a homomorphism of the group of fractional ideals of $S^{-1}A$, and the kernel consists of those fractional ideals of $A$ which meet $S$."

I am not sure if the statement about the kernel of this map is true. For example, consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\{1,3,9,\dotsc\}$ and $\mathfrak{a}=(1/2)\mathbb{Z}=\{n/2\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Then $\mathfrak{a}\cap S=S\ne\emptyset$, so $\mathfrak{a}$ meets $S$. If the statement were true, we would have $S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}=S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$, which is of course false (for instance, $1/2\in S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}\setminus S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$).

Am I right? Is this statement false? If the answer is yes, then what should be the real kernel?

Comment: What does your "$\mathfrak a = \mathbb Z/2$" mean? The notation $\mathbb Z/2$ doesn't make sense in the context of this problem: it should be a fractional ideal in $S^{-1}A = \mathbb Z[1/3]$. Do you understand what fractional ideals are?

Comment: The map $\mathfrak{a}\mapsto S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}$ is a homomorphism from the group of fractional ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ to the group of fractional ideals of $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$. $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is an abelian group which is closed under multiplication by $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is a fractional ideal of $\mathbb{Z}, isn't it?
Tell me if I'm understanding something wrong, please.

Comment: Do you mean the integers mod 2? That is not a fractional ideal of $\mathbf Z$. Fractional ideals of an integral domain $R$ are certain $R$-modules *inside* the fraction field of $R$. It looks like you are confusing “quotient ring” and “fractional ideal”.

Comment: No, by $\mathbb{Z}/2$ I mean $\{n/2\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It would have been clearer if you wrote $(1/2)\mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb Z/2$. For fractional ideals $\mathfrak a$ in $A$, containing a unit of $A$ does *not* make $\mathfrak a = A$ unless $\mathfrak a$ is an ordinary ideal (meaning it is *in* $A$). For example, $(1/2)\mathbb Z$ is a fractional ideal for $\mathbb Z$ and it contains a unit of $\mathbb Z$ (in fact it contains $\mathbb Z$) but it is not $\mathbb Z$.  A fractional ideal $\mathfrak a$ meets $S$ iff $S^{-1}A \subset S^{-1}\mathfrak a$. (If $\mathfrak a \subset A$ then $\mathfrak a = A$ if and only if $\mathfrak a$ meets $A^\times$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *ordinary* ideals $\mathfrak a$ in a Dedekind domain $A$ (or really in an arbitrary commutative ring $A$), we have $\mathfrak a = A$ if and only if $\mathfrak a$ contains a unit of $A$.  But for fractional ideals $\mathfrak a$ of
a Dedekind domain $A$, it is not true that $\mathfrak a = A$ if and only if $\mathfrak a$ contains a unit of $A$. For example, taking $A = \mathbf Z$, a fractional ideal $(1/n)\mathbf Z$ where $n \geq 2$ contains all of $\mathbf Z$ and doesn't equal $\mathbf Z$.

What we can say for fractional ideals $\mathfrak a$ of a Dedekind domain $A$ is that $A \subset \mathfrak a$ if and only if $\mathfrak a$ contains a unit of $A$.
(If $\mathfrak a$ is an ordinary ideal, so $\mathfrak a \subset A$, then the conditions $\mathfrak a = A$ and $A \subset \mathfrak a$ are equivalent.)

In the case of the localization $S^{-1}A$ of a Dedekind domain $A$, fractional ideals $\mathfrak a$ of $A$ lead to fractional ideals $S^{-1}\mathfrak a$ of $S^{-1}A$ and this is multiplicative: $S^{-1}(\mathfrak a\mathfrak b) = (S^{-1}\mathfrak a)(S^{-1}\mathfrak b)$. So by induction, $S^{-1}(\mathfrak a^n) = (S^{-1}\mathfrak a)^n$ for nonnegative integers $n$, and to show this is true for negative $n$ as well we just need to check it for $n=-1$: localization sends inverse to inverses, i.e., $S^{-1}(\mathfrak a^{-1}) = (S^{-1}\mathfrak a)^{-1}$.  That is immediate from the formula $S^{-1}(\mathfrak a\mathfrak b) = (S^{-1}\mathfrak a)(S^{-1}\mathfrak b)$ by using $\mathfrak b = \mathfrak a^{-1}$.
Note that inversion on fractional ideals reverses containments: $\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak b \Leftrightarrow \mathfrak b^{-1} \subset \mathfrak a^{-1}$ for fractional ideals $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ of the Dedekind domain $A$, and applying that reasoning to the Dedekind domain $S^{-1}A$ we get $S^{-1}\mathfrak a \subset S^{-1}\mathfrak b \Leftrightarrow S^{-1}(\mathfrak b^{-1}) \subset S^{-1}(\mathfrak a^{-1})$ because localizing at $S$ commutes with inversion on fractional ideals.

Now I can answer your question: for which $\mathfrak a$ does $S^{-1}\mathfrak a = S^{-1}A$?  Since $S^{-1}A$ is the fractional ideal of $S^{-1}A$ generated by $1$, we have $S^{-1}A \subset S^{-1}\mathfrak a$ if and only if $1 \in S^{-1}\mathfrak a$, which is equivalent to saying $\mathfrak a$ meets $S$. Thus
\begin{align*}
S^{-1}A = S^{-1}\mathfrak a & \Leftrightarrow S^{-1}A \subset S^{-1}\mathfrak a \text{ and } S^{-1}\mathfrak a \subset S^{-1}A \\ & \Leftrightarrow S^{-1}A \subset S^{-1}\mathfrak a \text{ and } S^{-1}A \subset S^{-1}(\mathfrak a^{-1}).
\end{align*}
Therefore $S^{-1}A = S^{-1}\mathfrak a$ if and only if $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak a^{-1}$ both meet $S$. There is the criterion you were seeking.

Example: $A = \mathbf Z$, $S = \{1,3,9,\ldots\}$, and $\mathfrak a = (1/2)\mathbf Z$.  Then $S^{-1}A = \mathbf Z[1/3]$ and $\mathfrak a$ meets $S$ since $\mathfrak a \supset \mathbf Z$, but $\mathfrak a^{-1} = 2\mathbf Z$ does *not* meet $S$, and this is consistent with $S^{-1}\mathfrak a = (1/2)\mathbf Z[1/3]$ not being equal to $\mathbf Z[1/3]$.

The criterion that $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak a^{-1}$ both meet $S$ is symmetric in the roles of $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak a^{-1}$, which isn't a surprise since fractional ideals are a group and the condition $S^{-1}A = S^{-1}\mathfrak a$ is  equivalent to $S^{-1}A = S^{-1}(\mathfrak a^{-1})$, so whatever the criterion is should be applicable to $\mathfrak a$ if and only if it is applicable to $\mathfrak a^{-1}$. The rule "$\mathfrak a$ meets $S$" is not equivalent to "$\mathfrak a^{-1}$ meets $S$" when $\mathfrak a$ is a general fractional ideal of $A$. Note, however, that if $\mathfrak a$ is an *ordinary ideal* of $A$ (meaning $\mathfrak a \subset A$), then the symmetry between the roles of $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak a^{-1}$ is broken: if $\mathfrak a \subset A$ then $A \subset \mathfrak a^{-1}$ so $\mathfrak a^{-1}$ automatically meets $S$ for every multiplicative subset $S$ of $A$, and in that case we recover (for Dedekind domains) the old relation for all *ordinary ideals* (but not all fractional ideals!) that $S^{-1}A = S^{-1}\mathfrak a$ if and only if $\mathfrak a$ meets $S$.